# Failed to fetch PPA Error (Deluge)

Tags: updates, update-manager, ppa, deluge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

How do I fix this error?

```
 W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,
 W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found,
 W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found,
 E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[image: Error even on Update Manager]

The same error occur when I tried,

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: It could be that the ppa `deluge-team` is not working properly so better remove that ppa from the `sources.list` or via `add-apt-repository --remove theDelugeTeamPPA` and `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: I cannot find it in  > sources.list I don't know if it works for the repository removal. this works: > sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:deluge-team/ppa I just found out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Deluge packages on Quantal, as [you can see on Launchpad's PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~deluge-team/+archive/ppa). To use Deluge, you need to edit the Deluge PPA entry to search packages for Precise in `software-properties-gtk`, changing the **Distribution:** field from `quantal` to `precise`:

[image: Distribution Changing]

After that, `sudo apt-get update` will show no errors about this repository.

Comment: How would you do this from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the fix. 
Use this command on terminal.

> sudo add-apt-repository -r  ppa:deluge-team/ppa

(THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED, SINCE IT WILL REMOVE THE REPOSITORY)

Comment: This will remove the repository. Is it what you want?